# Transformation into compound sentence

Tags: transformation

What will be the compound sentence of the following complex sentence ?

"If I did not help the autuority , the guilty would run away ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an odd question. Your sentence is complex, but it is also conditional. The standard way to form a conditional sentence in English is through a complex sentence. It is, however, possible to form a conditional in a non-standard way.

**I may not assist the police, and, consequently, the guilty will certainly escape** means much the same as **If I do not assist the police, the guilty will certainly escape.**